# How can I make it so that ltree subpath only returns a value if it has > 2 items?

Tags: postgresql

I have an ltree column containing a list of ancestors + itself... So imagine the following records

| id | path | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | root |
| 2 | 1.2 | child |
| 3 | 1.2.3 | grandchild |

I am trying to select the parent from each record, and I thought I could do:

```
SELECT id, path, ltree2text(subpath(path, -2, 1))::integer as parent FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

But the results from that are:

| id | path | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1.2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1.2.3 | 2 |

I am expecting the root record (id 1)'s parent to be `null`, not `1` ... Is there a way to perform that select for ltree2text only if there are 2 or more elements? so that a parent for either a null path or one with only one item will return `null` ?

*** UPDATE ***

I figured out I can do:

```
SELECT id, 
       path, 
       CASE WHEN nlevel(path) > 1 THEN 
         ltree2text(subpath(path, -2, 1))::integer 
       ELSE 
         null 
       END as parent
FROM table
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

And this does what I want, but I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this?